# What is the running time of this recursive function?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

I am having difficulty figuring out the running time of this simple recursive function.

```
void myRecur(int n)
{
   if (n < 1) return;
   cout << n << " ";
   myRecur(n/2);
   cout << n << " ";
   myRecur(n/2);
}
```

I figured that it prints: 4 2 1 1 2 1 1 4 2 1 1 2 1 1 for myRecur(4).

Also, is this function similar to the tree traversal function in terms of time complexity?

Any advice on understanding recursion and detailed explanation of the running time of this particular problem are much appreciated.

Comment: Once you know what it prints, you know the running time, right?  So what does it print?

Comment: _I figured that it prints: 4 2 1 1 2 1 1 4 2 1 1 2 1 1_ -- obviously this is when the initial `n` is 8, so you know that `myRecur(8)` calls the function 15 times, or `2n-1` times. If you vary the initial input to, say, 16, 32, 64, 128, does a pattern become evident (or, examining the code itself, can you predict if such a pattern will be present)? If so, you have found your answer. As to _similar to the tree traversal_ - not if it's a tree traversal that people count on for efficiency!

Comment: @mah Thanks for your input. You're right, I can increase the size of the input and guess the running time based on the results. However, I am looking for a generic method to analyze the function, i.e. use the recurrence relation or recursion tree to find the running time.

Comment: @root different recursion functions have different criteria about how they will recurse in relation to the input they have been provided. Since these criteria are not generic, your solution is not generic either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great spot to use a recurrence relation! Let's let T(n) be the amount of time the algorithm takes to run on an input of size n. Then

- T(0) = 1, since the base case does a constant amount of work, and
- T(n) = 2T(⌊n/2⌋) + 1, since each other case makes two recursive calls to problems of size n/2 and does an additional constant amount of work.

The goal now is to find some sort of expression that describes T(n) non-recursively. There are a lot of ways to do this. Look up the iteration method and the recursion-tree method for some examples of this. The fastest way to do this is to use the wonderfully-named Master Theorem, which lets you directly determine the time complexity from the recurrence relation. In this case, the master theorem says that this solves to T(n) = Θ(n).

Comment: Thank you so much! Just a follow-up, for the base case, why is it T(1) = 1? I thought it's T(0) = 1 because the base case occurs when n < 1... Might be misunderstanding something...

Comment: `cout << n` is O(log n), not O(1).

Comment: @PaulHankin That's a great point - I'd never thought of that before!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are interested in worst case so the code complexity is **Ο(n)**. For a given **n** your function will run **2n-1** times at most.

For a better understanding try to build a call tree.

```
            n
    n/2           n/2
n/4    n/4     n/4    n/4
...
```

There are  ⌊**log<sub>2</sub>(n)**⌋ levels. Each level has **2<sup>lvl</sup>** items. The total number of items is **2n - 1**.